# SQL: How to select by linked table column where there are multiple rows in linked table?

Tags: mysql

Let's presume I have the following two tables:

> Contacts
>
> > id (INT PRIMARY)
> >
> > name (VARCHAR)
>
> Emails
>
> > email_Id (INT PRIMARY)
> >     
> >  email_address (VARCHAR)
> >     
> >  contacts_id (INT > the link to the Contacts table)

These two tables are linked by contacts_id, so basically each contact may have multiple e-mail addresses associated to it. How could I make an SQL query, which finds EVERY contact, whose email address (email_address) field is **LIKE** *query*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ContactId FROM Contacts AS C
INNER JOIN Email AS E ON E.contactID = C.ContactID
WHERE E.Email LIKE '%Text%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use left joins it will give all results

```
select contacts.* from contacts left join Emails on(contacts.id=Emails.contacts_id) where Emails.email_address LIKE '%text%'
```

ignore syntax error if any.